# Time-based while loop

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to get the while & the If loop to read in the time correctly, but it doesn't end the program when the right time has hit. I tried using single quotes `''` and double quotes `""`, as well as different syntax like (`-eq`, `-match`, `-ne`) to see if any of those work....and they don't.

#### Program Goal: loops until it hits 07:00am

```
# While the value is 1.
while ($value -ne 2)
{   
    # Value should be 1 in order to stay in loop.
    $value = 1

    # Get's the time in 24hr format
    $time = get-date -Format HH:mm:ss

    # For Debugging; Writes out Time
    Write-Output $time

    # Creates a Pop-Up Windows that prevents the computer from timing out; runs every 15 minutes.
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

    $wshell.Popup("Operation Completed",0,"Done",0x1)

    # Causes the Program to wait to send the Enter Keystroke.
    Sleep 4

    # Sends the Enter Keystroke.
    $wshell.sendkeys('~')

    # Causes the Program to wait to send the Enter Keystroke in seconds (900sec = 15 Minutes).
    Sleep 4

    # If Condition; If the time is over 2am then the program quits.
    If ($time -eq "02:03:00")
    {
        # While Loop End Condition
        $value = 2

        # "Debugging Output"
        Write-Output $value
        Write-Output $time
    }

    Else
    {
        # While Loop Condition
        $value = 1

        # "Debugging Output"
        Write-Output $value
        Write-Output $time
    }
}

# "Debugging Output"
Write-Output "End"
Write-Output $time
Write-Output $value
```

Comment: As aside: You are constantly creating a new Com object inside the loop without ever trying to release it from memory after it has done its `PopUp` job. This will eventually exhaust your computers memory. Create the `$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell` BEFORE you enter the loop and clean up afterwards with `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wshell) | Out-Null`

Comment: Thanks so much! I keep forgetting that needs to be done (used to other languages lol). I fixed it in my code. Should i post the finished product here? The programs mainly to keep a pc device from auto-locking at work (got permission to write a script for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition should do the work:

```bsh
if ((Get-Date) -gt (Get-Date -Hour 7 -Minute 0 -Second 0)) {
  # While Loop End Condition
  $value = 2
  # more actions 
}
```

It's comparing the current time with the `DateTime` object with current day, but time set to `07:00:00`.

Keep in mind two things:

1. It will allow the loop to run only between midnight and 7AM. If you want to start the script the day before you need to adjust the conditions.
2. It might be more readable to not use `if`, but put the condition directly in `while()` like this:

```bsh
while ((Get-Date) -lt (Get-Date -Hour 7 -Minute 0 -Second 0)) {
  # do something
}
```

Currently, you're checking for exact time, so *in theory* the end condition might be met, However, if it hits that specific line one second before/after, it won't stop the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help! You solved the answer to the question I had :)!

Answer (score 2):

The chances are really low that your if-statement will become true. Because your while loop takes at least 8 (2x Start-Sleep and other work) seconds until a new beginning. That means the $time variable will probably never be exactly 02:03:00. In this case I would not go for the exact time. Instead I would check if it's 02:03:00 or later. Try that:

```
$time = Get-Date

if ($time -ge (Get-Date -Hour 02 -Minute 03 -Second 00))
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Finished Code (at least this version of it anyhow). Appreciate the help too :)!

```
<### 

    Program Goal: Prevent PC Timeout/Sleep; also loops until it hits 07:00am 
    Date: 10/14/19
    Version: 1.2

###>

# Creates a Pop-Up Windows that prevents the computer from timing out; runs every 15 minutes.
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

# Get's the time in 24hr format
$time = get-date

# While the value is not equal to 2.
while ($value -ne 2)
{   
    # Value should be 1 in order to stay in loop.
    $value = 1

    $wshell.Popup("Operation Completed", 5,"Done", 1)

    # Causes the Program to wait to send the Enter Keystroke.
    Sleep 2

    # If Condition; If the time is over 7am then the program quits.
    if ((Get-Date) -gt (Get-Date -Hour 7 -Minute 0 -Second 0)) 
    {
        # While Loop End Condition
        $value = 2
    }

    else
    {
        # While Loop Condition
        $value = 1

        # Causes the Program to wait (900sec = 15 Minutes) to prevent PC Timeout, will re-run again after Sleep.
        Sleep 900
    }

}

# Cleans up the COM Object
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wshell) | Out-Null
```